# Why this huge difference in execution time happens for this tiny change into c code?

Tags: c, performance

The below code in unix takes ~9s reported by `time` command.

```
int main()
{
    double u = 0;
    double v = 0;
    double w = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < 1000000000;++i) {
        v *= w;
        u += v;
    }
    printf("%lf\n",u);
}
```

I don't understand why the execution times almost double when i change `v *= w;`with`v *= u;`

Comment: `w` is always zero. The compiler is probably smart enough not to run that loop at all in the first case since `v` will also always be zero, and thus `u` too. (Might be harder to figure out with the interdependency between u and v.)

Comment: Did you look at the generated code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you change `v *= w` to `v *= u` then there is an inter-dependency between the 2 statements. Hence, the first statement has to be completed before executing `u += v` which could be the reason for the increased performance as the compiler can't parallelize the execution.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the compiler sees that w is never modified, and so can be compiled into a constant whereas the variable u is modified and so must have its own memory.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler optimizes v*= w; to v = 0; and the probably u += v to u = 0; So those operations never happen.

Here is the test i did. Every version was done 10 times and averaged.

```
for (i = 0;i < 1000000000;++i) {
    v *= w;
    u += v;
}
```

4.0373 seconds

```
for (i = 0;i < 1000000000;++i) {
    v *= u;
    u += v;
}
```

7.3733 seconds

```
for (i = 0;i < 1000000000;++i) {
    v *= 0;
    u += 0;
}
```

4.0149 seconds

Comment: why it doesn't do the same with `v *= u;` since is 0 as well

Comment: Probably can't optimize v *= u and u += v out since they are dependant on each other.

Comment: @curious it takes an extra step of reasoning though (it first has to find out that `v` is constant zero, then that `u` never changes and remains zero - in the other case, it just has to see that `w` is constant zero), that could make a difference.